# How to fix app submission error of 1300?

Tags: c#, vb.net, uwp, windows-store, .net-native

My application submission failed and I received a mail from the Store that says it failed with error code 1300 but not much more information. I noticed that it failed in the preprocessing.

Build/Run/Packaging/WACK all pass on my local machine.

Answer (score 1):

(I work on the .NET Native runtime and compiler team)

We've identified an issue with the way some of our targets behave when you have configuration values that aren't "DEBUG" or "RELEASE". For example, most Unity apps use a config named "Master" and it causes us to not properly wire up one of our dependency packages (Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework-xxx). As you've noticed, this causes a great deal of headache for the Store ingestion pipeline as your package now looks somewhat malformed.

The fix is currently out for review and we'll get it published as with 5.3.3 of Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform. It will take a bit to make it through review but you should see that update available shortly.

Workaround
In the interim, there are two ways we recommend to avoid this issue. First, downgrade Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform to version 5.2.3. The bug only exists in 5.3+ so you'll be safe on that version. Alternately, If there are fixes you need in 5.3+, you can also avoid the issue by adding this property to the UWP proj:

```
<UseDotNetNativeSharedAssemblyFrameworkPackage>false</UseDotNetNativeSharedAssemblyFrameworkPackage>
```

EDIT: the fix for this issue is now live and available as version 5.3.3 of Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform